# Overwriting a previous highscore using sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

I've managed to get my score to save to SharedPreferences correctly as well as it saving to highscore. However when checking if the previous score is better than the saved highscore, it always saves over it no matter what and I don't know why.

```
// save score and time if current score is > than current highscore and time is > than current hightime
        if (score > scorePreferences.getInt("highscore", 0) && time > timePreferences.getInt("hightime", 0)) {
            highscorePreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("highscore", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorHighscore = highscorePreferences.edit();
            editorHighscore.putInt("highscore", score);
            editorHighscore.commit();

            timePreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("hightime", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorHightime = timePreferences.edit();
            editorHightime.putInt("hightime", time);
            editorHightime.commit();
        }
```

It then gets read in gameoveractivity and highscore activity using this code:

```
// load score from last session
    private void load() {
        // get score and set text field
        scorePreferences = getSharedPreferences("score", 0);        
        score = scorePreferences.getInt("score", 0);
        scoreValue.setText(Integer.toString(score));

        // get time and set text field
        timePreferences = getSharedPreferences("time", 0);
        time = timePreferences.getInt("time", 0);
        timeValue.setText(Integer.toString(time) + " seconds");

        // get highscore and set text field
        highscorePreferences = getSharedPreferences("highscore", 0);
        highscore = highscorePreferences.getInt("highscore", 0);
        highscoreValue.setText(Integer.toString(highscore));
    }
```

Comment: Break down your first line like this so you can find out why: `int currentHighScore = scorePreferences.getInt("highscore", 0); int currentHighTime = timePreferences.getInt("hightime", 0); Log.i("scores",currentHighScore + " " + currentHighTime); if (score > currentHighScore && time > currentHighTime) {`

Comment: Is a higher time better?

Comment: By the way, you don't need separated SharedPreferences files for each type of entry. That's why the entries have keys. A SharedPreferences is a lot like a HashMap. Also, since you're using a member variable for each of your instances of shared preferences, you don't have to keep calling getSharedPreference after the first time you do it in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should this:

```
if (score > scorePreferences.getInt("highscore", 0)...
```

...not be something like:

```
if (score > highscorePreferences.getInt("highscore", 0)...
```

The key "highscore" is in your preferences set with that same name. It looks like you are reading that key from the "score" preferences instead. It's not there, so the default of 0 is always being used.

Comment: Yes! Literally just realised this now. Also had to move the getting context to outside the if or else got a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you use same key for your sharedpreferences that is why the values override.
I would recommend using sqlite for storing top scores.

Answer (score 2):

Use one SharedPreferences object. To save, you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("score", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

int highscore = prefs.getInt("highscore", 0);
int hightime = prefs.getInt("hightime", 0);

if (score > highscore && time > hightime) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.editor();

    editor.putInt("highscore", score);
    editor.putInt("hightime", time);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Then load it, also use one SharedPreferences object:

```
private void load() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("score", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    score = prefs.getInt("score", 0);
    scoreValue.setText(Integer.toString(score));

    time = prefs.getInt("time", 0);
    timeValue.setText(Integer.toString(time) + " seconds");

    highscore = prefs.getInt("highscore", 0);
    highscoreValue.setText(Integer.toString(highscore));
}
```

NOTES:

- it's a good idea to use keys for prefs file name and variables, so that you can avoid easy typo mistakes when saving/retrieving variables, eg.

  ```
  public static final String PREFS_NAME = "score";
  public static final String KEY_HIGHSCORE = "highscore";
  public static final String KEY_HIGHTIME = "hightime";
  ```

then use it

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ClassNameWhereItsDeclared.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

editor.putInt(ClassNameWhereItsDeclared.KEY_HIGHSCORE, score);
```

etc.

- I don't see where you're saving time and score, but you can do it the same way as highscore and hightime